# How can i change the value of a TextView Instantly, as i push the update button that retrieves data from a Database?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, android-textinputlayout

```
public class UserprofileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // VARIABLES
    TextView fullName, userName, location, motorcycle;
    TextInputLayout fullNameInput, emailInput, motorcycleInput, passwordInput;

    // GLOBAL VARIABLES TO HOLD USER DATA INSIDE THIS ACTIVITY
    String _NAME, _USERNAME, _EMAIL, _LOCATION, _MOTORCYCLE, _PASSWORD;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_userprofile);

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        // HOOKS
        fullName = findViewById(R.id.profileFullName);
        userName = findViewById(R.id.profileUsername);
        location = findViewById(R.id.profileLocalization);
        motorcycle = findViewById(R.id.profileMotorcycle);
        fullNameInput = findViewById(R.id.profile_FullName);
        emailInput = findViewById(R.id.profile_Email);
        motorcycleInput = findViewById(R.id.profile_Motorcycle);
        passwordInput = findViewById(R.id.profile_Password);

        // SHOW ALL DATA
        showAllUserData();
    }

    private void showAllUserData() {

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        _NAME = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        _USERNAME = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        _EMAIL = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        _LOCATION = intent.getStringExtra("location");
        _MOTORCYCLE = intent.getStringExtra("motorcycle");
        _PASSWORD = intent.getStringExtra("password");
```

---

// this variable goes to (TextInputLayout "fullNameInput) and (TextView fullName) this goes to update the full name of the user and also is motorcycle brand. It should update both TextViews(Full Name and Motorcycle) with the data retrieved from the database at the same time and as soon as i would click the update button below the form. But it only updates after a new login. (The table name of the Database is users and the first child is the Username). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52JXR.png)

```
        fullName.setText(_NAME);
```

---

```
        userName.setText(_USERNAME);
        location.setText(_LOCATION);
        motorcycle.setText(_MOTORCYCLE);
        Objects.requireNonNull(fullNameInput.getEditText()).setText(_NAME);
        Objects.requireNonNull(emailInput.getEditText()).setText(_EMAIL);
        Objects.requireNonNull(motorcycleInput.getEditText()).setText(_MOTORCYCLE);
        Objects.requireNonNull(passwordInput.getEditText()).setText(_PASSWORD);
    }

    private boolean isNameChanged() {
        if (!_NAME.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(fullNameInput.getEditText()).getText().toString())) {
            reference.child(_USERNAME).child("name").setValue(fullNameInput.getEditText().getText().toString());
            fullName.getText().equals(_NAME);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isMotorcycleChanged() {
        if (!_MOTORCYCLE.equals(Objects.requireNonNull(motorcycleInput.getEditText()).getText().toString())) {
            reference.child(_USERNAME).child("motorcycle").setValue(motorcycleInput.getEditText().getText().toString());
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void update(View view) {
        if (isNameChanged() || isEmailChanged() || isMotorcycleChanged() || isPasswordChanged()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data has been Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data is the Same and therefore Cannot be Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not understandable what you want to try

Comment: what dont you understand @Ashish

Comment: is your onclicklistener not working ?

Comment: no my onclicklistener is working fine because it updates the data on the database. And saves the data updated on the TextInputLayouts. The only thing is that it doesnt update my two textviews. Can you see the image in attach?

Comment: Then you want to change the data also on click ?

Comment: Yes. I´ve already try this also : reference.child(_USERNAME).child("name").equals(fullName);

Comment: It will update in database not reflect on the screen so you can do this

Comment: reference.child(_USERNAME).child("name").setValue(fullName); this also doesnt work, it changes but the app crashes

Comment: try to console it and check the log